# How to create only one subscription from this two observables?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a function that reads data from a readable stream and then saves the result in Parse:

```
const { from } = require('rxjs');
const Observable = require('rxjs').Observable;
const jsArr = [];

fromStream(fs.createReadStream(req.file.path, 'utf-8').pipe(csv()))
        .map((data) => data.USERNAME)
        .subscribe(
            (data) => jsArr.push(data),
            (error) => console.log(error),
            () => {
                const CSVData = Parse.Object.extend('CSVData');
                const csv = new CSVData();
                csv.set('CSV',jsArr);

                from (csv.save())
                .subscribe(
                    () => res.json(serialize({type:'success'})),
                    (error) => console.log(error)
                );

            }
        );
```

it works really well, but I'd like to know if there is a way to do it in a more cleaner way, using only one subscriber.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do it like this but for obvious reasons I haven't tested it.

```
fromStream(fs.createReadStream(req.file.path, 'utf-8').pipe(csv()))
  .map((data) => data.USERNAME)
  .toArray(),
  .concatMap(jsArr => {
    const CSVData = Parse.Object.extend('CSVData');
    const csv = new CSVData();
    csv.set('CSV',jsArr);

    return from(csv.save());
  })
  .subscribe(
    () => res.json(serialize({type:'success'})),
    (error) => console.log(error)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

First `reduce` and get the result to save, and save the result:

```
 fromStream(fs.createReadStream(req.file.path, 'utf-8').pipe(csv()) )
            .map((data) => data.USERNAME)
            .reduce((acc, curr) => acc.push(curr), [])
            .switchMap(resultArray => {
                    const CSVData = Parse.Object.extend('CSVData');
                    const csv = new CSVData();
                    csv.set('CSV',resultArray);
                    return from (csv.save());

             }).subscribe(x =>{})
```

The above approach may be easier and follows good functional programming concepts, here you do not need to use the property `jsArr`.